# How can I make a connection to Postgresql?

Tags: spring, postgresql, spring-boot, microservices, spring-cloud

I am trying to connect to a service from a remote repo which has configuration to my application with Spring Cloud, for some reason I can't make it work.

The error I get:

> Description:
>
> Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and
> no embedded datasource could be configured.
>
> Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class
>
> Action:
> Consider the following:
>
> If you want an embedded database (H2, HSQL or Derby), please put it on the classpath.
>
> If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to activate it (the profiles default are currently active).

config-module/src/resources/some-service/some-service.yml:

```
spring:
  jpa:
    database: "PostgreSQL"
    show-sql: "true"
    properties:
      hibernate:
        dialect: "org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect"
  datasource:
    driver-class-name: "org.postgresql.Driver"
    url: "jdbc:postgresql://database:5432/some-path"
    username: "<some-user>"
    password: "<some-password>"
    validationQuery: "SELECT 1"
  sql:
    init:
      platform: "postgres"
```

config-module/src/resources/application.yml:

```
server:
  port: 8888
spring:
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        encrypt:
          enabled: true
          key:
        git:
          uri: https://github.com/<some-config-repo>
          searchPaths: <directory-in-config-repo>
          username: <some-user>
          password: <some-password>
```

some-service/src/resources/bootsrap.yml:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: <directory-in-config-repo>
  profiles:
    active:
      default
  cloud:
    config:
      uri: http://localhost:8888
```

I can run psql on cmd so there is no problem there.

I tried changing versions of pom files because I was using latest in all of them and thought maybe older versions would be more stable but no luck. I expect to reach the databasee page and my app to compile.

Comment: There are logs on the config client that might give you some hints

Comment: @spencergibb Well, it is just bunch of Hikari pooling errors with Spring exceptions, first exception is PSQLException.

Comment: What versions are you using? Bootstrap is no longer the default on later versions. How are you enabling it?

Comment: I am using the latest versions. Such as postgresql 42.6.0 and spring 3.1.1, spring cloud 2022.0.3 cloud config 4.0.3 etc.

Comment: I enable it with @EnableConfigServer in config-module package which is a microservice as the <some-service>

Comment: Bootstrap is not enabled by default. Include spring cloud starter bootstrap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exclude you auto config class :

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class })
```

Also also  make sure database with name `some-path` is exists

Comment: Yeah, that solved the issue but now I have another problem I can't get Hibernate to initialize my Entity class which is in <main-package>.model package. I added it with EntityScan but no luck